# tkinter python 3 : columnas y fila

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy usando Python idle por si necesitan saber mi editor, el problema es que cuando pongo el grid solo me deja en cuatro casillas, este es mi código para que lo revisen, gracias.

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> win = Tk()
>>> win.geometry('200x250')
''
>>> b1 = Button(win, text="1")
>>> b1.grid(row = 1, column = 5)
>>> b2 = Button(win, text="2")
>>> b2.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es poder tener filas o columnas competamente vacías ?

Answer (score 0):

No es que solo te permita posicionar cuatro widgets, es que tienes filas y columnas sin ningún contenido. Por defecto el peso de las filas y columnas es 0, lo que significa que no crecerán nada más que lo mínimo para contener sus widgets, si no hay nada tendrá un tamaño de 0.

La solución por tanto pasa por asignar a las columnas y filas un peso de 1 como mínimo, de forma que se asigna espacio extra a cada una:

```
import tkinter as tk


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('200x250')

for i in range(5):
    win.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
    win.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

b4 = tk.Button(win, text="4", bg="orange")
b4.grid(row=0, column=4)
b6 = tk.Button(win, text="6", bg="orange")
b6.grid(row=2, column=2)
b13 = tk.Button(win, text="13", bg="orange")
b13.grid(row=4, column=0)

win.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si además quieres que todas las celdas tenga el mismo tamaño, debes usar el argumento `uniform` pasando el mismo nombre de grupo a aquellas filas o columnas que quieras que tengan un tamaño uniforme entre si:

```
import tkinter as tk


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('200x250')

for i in range(5):
    win.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, uniform='row')
    win.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, uniform='col')

b4 = tk.Button(win, text="4", bg="orange")
b4.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="NSEW")
b6 = tk.Button(win, text="6", bg="orange")
b6.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="NSEW")
b13 = tk.Button(win, text="13", bg="orange")
b13.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

win.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dos observaciones:

- Usar wildcard para importar (`from modulo import *`)  es una mala práctica por múltiples razones, hace el código menos legible y explícito, importa todo el módulo al espacio de nombres actual cuando seguramente solo necesitamos algunas cosas y tiene el riesgo de provocar colisiones y solapamientos de nombres entre namespaces no deseados o inadvertidos.
- Recuerda llamar de forma explícita al ciclo principal de la app (`win.mainlopp()`) o a aplicación jamás iniciará. En tu caso lo hace porque usas el IDLE y está creado en tkinter, las aplicaciones que ejecutes en el se muestran porque usan el mainloop del propio IDE, pero no lo harán en otros IDES o al ejecutarlo mediante la terminal por ejemplo.